# vim-NERDTree: order bookmarks?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there a way to order the bookmarks I see with the NERDTree vim plugin?

I feel like this should be simple, but I don't know how to do this. I vim'ed `~/.NERDTreeBookmarks` and saw that in that file, the bookmarks are in the right order, but it seems to continuously reorganize the bookmarks according to the order I use them -- which is not what I want. I also did `:ReadBookmarks` command and that didn't seem to change order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, and managed to turn off NERDTree's wacky bookmark sorting. Open the `NERD_tree.vim` plugin file (usually `~/.vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim`). Search for this line:

```
call s:Bookmark.Sort()
```

There should be two instances of the line (in NERDTree version 4.2.0 they're on lines 209 and 286). Comment out both lines by adding `"` in front of them like this:

```
"call s:Bookmark.Sort()
```

Now you can edit `~/.NERDTreeBookmarks` and your bookmarks will show up in NERDTree in the same order as in the file. You can use `:ReadBookmarks` to refresh your bookmarks list after editing the file.

Comment: Yay! I gave up a long time ago, but I'm so glad someone noticed this question and answered it :)

Answer (score 5):

As an update to alxm's excellent answer above, the line(s) have been moved into a new file. On my hard drive it's in `~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim` (I use vundle). In a vanilla vim installation it would most likely be in `~/.vim/plugin/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim`.

#### 1. Edit your bookmark.vim file

I commented out the line that starts with `call sort...` (line 246), like this:

```
" This is in ~/.vim/<PLUGINDIR>/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim

" FUNCTION: Bookmark.Sort() {{{1
" Class method that sorts all bookmarks
function! s:Bookmark.Sort()
    let CompareFunc = function("nerdtree#compareBookmarks")
    "call sort(s:Bookmark.Bookmarks(), CompareFunc)
endfunction
```

#### 2. Quit vim

Exit out of vim because you want to reload your plugins, specifically NERDTree.

#### 3. Edit your ~/.NERDTreeBookmarks file.

Put them in the order you want them in. NERDTree now respects your wishes. Your solemn, heartfelt bookmark sorting wishes.

#### 4. Fire up vim again

Of course everyone already knows this, but I thought this answer needed a fourth step.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure since when though, you can now set `NERDTreeBookmarksSort` instead.

```
let g:NERDTreeBookmarksSort=0
```

Then edit `~/.NERDTreeBookmarks` as you want to order.

Check `:help NERDTreeBookmarksSort` for more detail.